# Can not filter variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr

My data structure like this

```
glimpse(DataGirne)
Observations: 6,984
Variables: 6
$ `S No` <chr> "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "1...
$ fiyat  <dbl> 275000, 185000, 60000, 70000, 85000, 60000, 195000, 78000, 
90000, 27000...
$ alan   <dbl> 240, 126, 90, 110, 100, 245, 210, 125, 88, 180, 0, 153, 0, 0, 
140, 83, ...
$ ilanno <chr> "95178", "95492", "79057", "79058", "66835", "67119", 
"87839", "67408",...
$ Tur    <fct> Satilik Villa, Satilik Daire, Satilik Daire, Satilik Daire, 
Satilik Dai...
$ Bolge  <chr> "Girne / Karaoğlanoğlu", "Girne / Girne Merkez", "Girne / 
Alsancak", "G...
```

when I use dplyr to filter or subset function (w/o dplyr) for filtering variable Tur as

```
DataKonut <- filter(DataGirne, DataGirne$Tur %in% c("Satilik Villa", 
"Satilik Daire"))
```

it gives 0 rows and table with "No data available in table". I can not even filter $Tur variable in any code always gives integer [0] 
How I can fix this?

Comment: Please provide the data in such a way we can reproduce the example

Comment: However, try `DataKonut <- dplyr::filter(DataGirne, Tur %in% c("Satilik Villa", "Satilik Daire") `

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kmA06jyjwUE06BJ2DvV3p8za8Hw2mbp4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Steve, please find an inspirational answer on how to prepare data [somewhere here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Beware of special characters, you had 'ı' instead of 'i' in the names. Also, you don't need to use the `$` accessor inside `dplyr` functions (though you can still use them).

```
DataKonut <- filter(DataGirne, Tur %in% c("Satılık Villa", "Satılık Daire"))
```

Comment: I guess this might cause problem but how I can fix it?